# Ado multiple range select

Tags: excel, ado, vba

I need get data from excel sheet from multiple range

```
RnG1 = "[" & SheetName & "$F1:G1000],"
RnG2 = "[" & SheetName & "$AI1:AI1000]"
RnG = RnG1 & RnG2
szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & RnG$ & ";"
```

But somthing is wrong, how to select multiple range to copy data?

Comment: You don't need to. Just select the specific fields you want (rather than SELECT *) from the F1:AI1000 range.

Comment: but I not need data in range between G:AI as there a lot of data wich wasting loading time

Comment: That's why I said select the specific fields and *don't* use SELECT *

Comment: So show me an example please as i dont understand what you talking about

Comment: Something like this: `szSQL = "SELECT [F1], [F2], [F30] FROM [" SheetName & "$F1:AI1000];"`

Comment: it can be like szSQL = "SELECT [F1:G1000], [AI1:AI1000] FROM [" SheetName & "$F1:AI1000];"  what is the syntax?

Comment: No it can't. You specify field names in the first part of the SELECT, not ranges.

Comment: but i need ranges, maybe i can do this with union two ranges?

Comment: I don't think you understand: selecting the fields will return all rows for those fields only so it is equivalent to what you asked for. Please try it.

Comment: i try it szSQL = "SELECT [F1], [AI1] FROM [" SheetName & "$F1:AI1000];" and get error "No value given to one or more required paramters"

Comment: Do you have column headers in the data? If so, use those; if not use [F1], [F2] etc to represent Field1, Field2 and so on. Do not use AI1.

Comment: Yes man your right! please answer in question so i cant close it. Thank you. And maybe is the way to get this data only distinct values? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118550/excel-vba-ado-distinct-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, if you don't have column headers:

```
szSQL = "SELECT [F1], [F2], [F30] FROM [" SheetName & "$F1:AI1000];"
```

where F1, F2 etc indicates Field1, Field2 and so on. If you do have column headers use those in place of the F1 and F2.